# Suddenly can't connect to internet but SSH is ok

Tags: wifi, pi-4, ubuntu, internet

I was trying to fix a problem where the Pi could only connect to the internet using the 5-GHz Wi-Fi but not the 2.4-GHz. After messing with the router and the network manager settings, I couldn't solve it but ended up not being able to connect to the internet anymore.

Lan displays unmanaged `wires.Wifi` can connect to the router and I can `ssh` into it, but I can't connect to the internet.

I have Ubuntu 19.10 on my Raspberry Pi 4.

```
ping google.com
result:temporary failure in name resolution
```

update:
fixed the `dns` problem by following

```
datawookie.netlify.com/blog/2018/10/dns-on-ubuntu-18.04
using `8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 now
```

result: the lan is working now, but for wifi:

```
ping google.com
result: temporary failure in name resolution
```

and

```
ping 4.2.2.4
result: from 192.168.31.219 icmp_seq1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

update:
sometimes it connects but with many packet loss

Please help!

Comment: Hello and welcome -- What about `ping 4.2.2.4`?

Comment: M. Rostami's point is that you probably have internet access, but no DNS server, which is how names like "google.com" are associated with an IP address.  Paste into the question the content of `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: @goldilcks thank you both! lan worked now but wifi still cannot, updates added.